# How to get the var declared in test1.py into test2.py, perform some operation on var in test2.py and get the updated value of var in test1.py?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

Assigning value to global var
For Example:

test1.py:

```
global var
var= 0  

def func1():
    print("The updated value of var is :"+var)
    #after the updated value perform some operation on var
    var=var*2  

def func3():
    global var
    print("The final value of var is :"+var)
```

test2.py:

```
from test1 import *
def func2():
    global var
    print("The initial value of var is :"+var)
    var = 2+3
    func1()
```

I intend to have the the following values of var:

the initial val of var in func1 of test2.py: 0

The updated value of var in func2 of test1.py: 5

The final value of var in func3 of test1.py: 10

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i notice in your code is the

```py
global var
```

on the first line. In python this is not needed. Any variable declared in the global scope is automatically global. You'd only need the global keyword inside of a function wanting to modify a global variable.

Another thing which you need to know about python is that a global var is only global for that specific file. It does not transfer over to other modules.

So now: how do you do what you want to do.

The only real way to keep this kind of state across modules i think, is to use some sort of container. Ill use a class but i'm sure things like a dict or a list would work fine. This way you also don't mess up the global scope as much, you can do this for multiple variables in one container, and you don't need the global keywords. This is the case because by importing test1 from test2, you would set var to 0 again as the whole test1 module is executed again. By is resolved by putting this shared container in a third module imported from both test1 and test2. I called this module "shared". The code would look like this:

test1.py:

```py
from test2 import func2
from shared import SharedContainer


def func1():
    print("The updated value of var is: {}".format(SharedContainer.var))
    # after the updated value perform some operation on var
    SharedContainer.var = SharedContainer.var*2


def func3():
    print("The final value of var is: {}".format(SharedContainer.var))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func2()
    func3()
```

test2.py

```py
from shared import SharedContainer


def func2():
    from test1 import func1
    print("The initial value of var is: {}".format(SharedContainer.var))
    SharedContainer.var = 2+3
    func1()
```

shared.py

```py
class SharedContainer:
    var = 0
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That was quite insightful.I am still learning my ways in Python.Thanks!

Comment: don't worry! Everyone needs to learn at the beginning. Good luck :)